# Bind Dependency Property in codebehind WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have XAML code:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="node" Height="10" Width="10" map:MapCanvas.Latitude="{Binding Latitude}" map:MapCanvas.Longitude="{Binding Longitude}"
                    Fill="Red" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Uniform" 
                </Ellipse>
```

and this

```
xmlns:map="clr-namespace:MapControl;assembly=MapControl"
```

here is the dependency property in MapCanvas class:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LatitudeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Latitude", typeof(double), typeof(MapCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, OnLatitudeLongitudePropertyChanged));


    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongitudeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Longitude", typeof(double), typeof(MapCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, OnLatitudeLongitudePropertyChanged));
```

I know there was similar questions but my question is how can I do bining in code behind same like in XAML code for longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 1):

```
node.SetBinding(MapCanvas.LatitudeProperty, new Binding("Latitude"));
```

You can Bind like this..