# How to bind DependencyProperty without using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

Well, I am doing a small project and I found it wasn't necessary to implemente a full MVVM.

I am trying to bind some properties in code behind, but cannot manage to make it works.

The point is the use of DependencyProperties and Binding in code behind.

I tried to follow these links and questions in SO:

[Bind Dependency Property in codebehind WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400892/bind-dependency-property-in-codebehind-wpf)

[How to: Create a Binding in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx)

[Bind Dependency Property, defined in Code-Behind, through Xaml to a Property in the DataContext of a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121877/bind-dependency-property-defined-in-code-behind-through-xaml-to-a-property-in)

But they are related to MVVM or at least I cannot adapt the code in my case.

The example should be very simple.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Label Name="_lblCurrentPath"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomPathLabel}"
        ToolTip="{Binding CurrentPath}"
        Content="{Binding CurrentPath, Mode=TwoWay,
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBindings();
}

#region Properties

public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPathProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentPath", typeof(String), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnCurrentPathChanged));


public string CurrentPath
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(CurrentPathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentPathProperty, value); }
}


#endregion

#region Bindings

private void SetBindings()
{
    // Label CurrentPath binding
    Binding _currentPath = new Binding("CurrentPath");
    _currentPath.Source = CurrentPath;
    this._lblCurrentPath.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, _currentPath);
}

#endregion

#region Methods

private void Refresh()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Refresh!");
}

private string Search()
{
    WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new WinForms.FolderBrowserDialog();

    WinForms.DialogResult _dResult = dialog.ShowDialog();

    switch(_dResult)
    {
        case WinForms.DialogResult.OK:
            CurrentPath = dialog.SelectedPath;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return CurrentPath;
}

#endregion

#region Events

private static void OnCurrentPathChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow instance = d as MainWindow;
    instance.Refresh();
}

public void OpenSearchEclipsePath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentPath = Search();
}

public void RefreshEclipsePath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

Any idea?

.If this is a bad practice and I should use MVVM comments are welcome, of ourse.

.Also... Related to `Command` property. In this case where I don't want to use a MVVM approach, is it better to register events? I found the use of custom command bindings a little bit tedious.

Comment: Its bad practice, you should use MVVM (you said we could comment ;) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can totally use bindings without MVVM. I wouldn't reccommend it, as the code is a lot cleaner when you use MVVM, but *it can be done*. All you need to do is put this line in your constructor:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Now your view is also your view model! Like I said, not a good idea.

Now, the code you have has a `DependencyProperty` in your `MainWindow` class. **Don't do that**. It serves absolutely no purpose. DPs are there so *parent* controls can give a binding to them. `MainWindow` has no parent; so a DP is useless.

All you need to do is set up a regular property:

```
public string CurrentPath
{
    get { return currentPath; }
    set
    {
         currentPath = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And then have `MainWindow` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (did I mention that it makes more sense to use a simple view model?).

To answer your `Command` question. Yes, if you are opposed to using commands, just register for the events. However, `Command` is a really nice way to get user clicks into the view model without breaking MVVM. The syntax isn't *that* bad. If you are going the "View as a View Model" approach anyways though, `Command` doesn't buy you much.

Comment: Thanks. It was easy. Yes, in the end I think I will use a MVVM approach. I used to create them custom, but I found very nice frameworks like mvvmlight or caliburn

Comment: @blacai Go right ahead and use your favorite framework, but it takes me all of five minutes to set up my own for each new project I do. It *really* isn't that hard. Glad to hear you are going to do it the right way though!

Comment: Well, at the moment I don't have favorite framework. Like I said I use to create my own but I see a lot of questions about them and would be nice to take a look :)

Comment: @blacai Meh, 98% of the time frameworks make my life harder, so I try and avoid them unless I *really* need them. Good luck in your search though.